# Neutral wiring in a panel

Tags: wiring

in a panel does it matter if the neutral wire goes to a different side of the panel than its corresponding hot wire?

or

can I connect two neutrals in a junction box that go back to different junction bars on the panel?

Comment: The second question here sounds like you are asking about joining/splicing neutrals (ie, two runs from the service box to the junction, and joined in the junction) which you NEVER do. If that's not what you mean, clarify. If it is, don't.

Answer (score 2):

In a main service panel; where the grounded (neutral) is bonded, you can land the grounded (neutral) conductor at either bus bar.

In a panel where the grounded (neutral) and grounding bus bars are separate, you can only land a grounded (neutral) conductor on the grounded (neutral) bus bar.  In this case, you'll either have to install a grounded (neutral) bar on each side of the panel, or route all the grounded (neutral) conductors to the same bar.

Answer (score -2):

The neutral bars should be grounded.  Thus, it doesn't matter what neutral bar you connect to.  If it does cause an issue, it's because one of the neutral bars isn't grounded.  The fix would be to ground that neutral bar.

Comment: You CANNOT just "ground" a neutral bar. It's not that simple.